# Electric field at a perpendicular distance of R from the centre of an inverted hollow hemisphere of radius R

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

I had 2 ideas to solve this problem. The first one was the standard integration technique and this is where I have an issue. Basically I considered elemental rings and using the result of electric field along the axis of a ring I wrote the electric field at the required point and integrated it. Here is my work.[image]

This is wrong as I solved it using the 2nd idea which uses the concept of solid angle and avoids the integration to get the final result as: $${\sigma\over 2\epsilon}\left[1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right] $$.

I think the mistake lies in the way the rings have been chosen as the final expression seems to be very similar to the electric field due to a hollow hemisphere at it's center. Also is the idea of varying theta work as it only covers 2D only.  I see no mistakes in the integration part and the limits. Could someone please point out my mistake?

Edit: Does it need the concept of double integrals?

Comment: Isn't it easier to use $z$ as the integrating variable instead of $\theta$?

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient I am sorry I don't get you. Could you point me to an example of another question where z is used? Also why is this wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong. It's just weird. Nevermind that. I suspect the problem in your work is when you replaced $dq$ with $\sigma (2 \pi r) (r \sin{\theta} d \theta)$. What you're calling $d \theta$ in $r \sin{\theta} d \theta$ isn't the infinitesimal change in $\theta$ as defined in your figure.

Comment: @boomavijay The width of each ring is not $r \text d \theta$. It's $r \text d \theta / \cos \theta$. Convince yourself by comparing a ring at the equator and a ring near the south pole; they do not have the same width for the same $\text d \theta$.

Comment: @user7777777 Thanks a lot! It makes sense now that you mention it. Did u come up the cosine factor just by observation?

Comment: @boomavijay I have enough experience to get it by observation. A helpful tip would to be check critical points. In your example, when $\theta = 0$, the width is exactly $r \text d \theta$. So we can rule out $\sin \theta$ (which is $0$) and $1/ \sin \theta$ (which is $\infty$). Then at $\theta = \pi/2$, the width goes to $\infty$. This tells us that it must be $1/ \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of each ring is not $r \text d \theta$. It's $r \text d \theta /\cos\theta$. You should be able to see this by comparing a ring at the equator and a ring near the south pole; they do not have the same width for the same $\text d \theta$.